# Connect Elastic Search Index with Google Data Studio

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, looker-studio, elk

I want to connect my `Elastic Search DB` with `Google Data Studio` to view my `index` data in Charts. I know that Elastic Search is loaded with Kibana which helps to create and view Charts. But I want to use my index as a data source in Google Data Studio and view Charts.

I found that there is Elastic Search Connector available in Google Data Studio to make it work. Link: https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/data-sources. But I can't find any proper documentation or steps for it. If any one uses `Elastic Search index` with `Google Data Studio`, Please suggest me steps to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

None of the existing [Data Studio Partner Connectors](https://datastudio.google.com/data) support Elasticsearch yet. The [link](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/data-sources) you provided shows that there is high user interest in this connector (i.e. users want to connect to this data source) and medium level of developer interest (some developers want to develop this connector).

Since existing published partner connector do not support this source, you can try creating you own [Community Connector](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/get-started) to connect to the [Elasticsearch REST API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs.html).